# c# get youtube subcriber count on a channel without api or gdata?

Tags: c#, youtube, getelementbyid

I am trying to figure out how to get the subscriber count for a channel by using elementids but it is a div and I don't know how to get the value of a div if anyone can help me out I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It seems the class of the Subscriber count is called "stat-value".

Simply use GetElementByClassName or the appropriate equivalent to get the value of the "stat-value" span.